# New server, how can i set my dns up for my domain name

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, name

I have a domain name registered through godaddy that I used for a previous site. I have set up my own server for my new buisness and I have it all running the way I want except the domain name. I have bind running on my server and I am using webmin/virtualmin to manage everything. How can I point my domain name at my server. When i tell godaddy to use the ip as the dns server it tells me i  have an invalid tld. That and it want's at least 2 dns servers. I really need some help here.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use godaddy's public facing DNS servers and use your server for your internal purposes? That would probably be the easiest way to get the functionality you're looking for.

Assuming you're hosting a website, set the A record to point to your server's WAN IP.

Comment: ok but how, i am a complete noob when it comes to dns stuff. Ive been using the server software for years on my vpn but iv'e never had to set up dns before. And will that allow me to setup other named virtual hosts like for example if the site is example.com, can i make an name.example.com too if i am using their dns servers. and how would i do that

Comment: Yes, you can add quite a few sub-domains on the basic package.  If you have a lot of sub-domains a premium package is available.

Answer (score 0):

You dont want to redirect the DNS you want to redirect the DNS records.

Specifically the A record and the MX record are probably the most important for you.

The A record is for your website and the MX record is for your Email.

Direct those to the public IP address where you'll be hosting the web/email and you'll be good to go, providing you've opened the ports on your firewall/router.